# How to display file containing old extended-ASCII code-page characters?

Tags: character-encoding

How can I setup Emacs to be able to display the content of an old file that contains non-ASCII 8-bit characters that we encoded using a code-page my system does not seem to support?

I have a file that has most probably been written in Germany in the days of 8-bit extended ASCII and Emacs does not display those characters properly.  I was thinking I code tell Emacs to try various encoding and see if text would show up.  Encoding like [Windows 1250 code-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) or some others.

Can this be done in Emacs?

Comment: You should also try `iso-8859-1`. `C-x RET c iso8859-1 RET C-x C-f <filename> RET` should open it with that coding system. The coding system is indicated on the mode line at left as `1: `.With some experience, you can tell what coding system was used, when you open the file with `M-x find-file literally` or with `od -c` from the command line and looking at the non-ascii chars.

Comment: The file I'm testing this with is a DOS-line termination file.  It is identified as iso-8859-1.   I presume that file was created with a pre-Unicode coding system most probably in a German speaking country.

Comment: I  found out that loading the file in Firefox detects the encoding, which turned out to be GBK (simplified chinese).  Knowing the encoding I can then use the method you described to open the file with GBK encoding and then I can tried to read the Chinese just fine ;-)

Comment: @Nick if you turn your answer in using the `universal-coding-system-argument` command into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'll try, but it's going to take me a few days: writing a good answer is different from throwing out crazy suggestions in a comment :-)

Comment: If you don't have time or if you prefer I can try writing something up later.

Comment: That's fine with me: that's part of how the site works.

Comment: OK, I'm busy ATM but I'll learn more about encoding and if @aadcg is OK with that I'll write something that integrate your answer, his answer and what I have learned.

Comment: OK, I'm busy at the moment and I need to learn more on encoding.  I'' learn more on encoding and I'll add an answer that includes what you said and what @aadcg said if that's fine to you both.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system` and select the desired coding system.

This is, by default, bound to `C-x RET f`.

Notice that `C-x RET` is a prefix map.  For more info, `C-x RET C-h` (or equivalently `C-x C-m C-h`).

Comment: Thanks.  The docstring of that command states `Make CODING-SYSTEM used for communicating with other X clients`.  Is this only meant to be used on Emacs running in graphics mode over X-Windows, or is this just an obsolete description?

Comment: After reading the docstring of `set-selection-coding-system`, it seems that X is relevant for clipboard support and related functionality. I can give a better answer, please check the edited version.